# Moving off of [node] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I have been checking each of the Node.JS questions with the node tag and removing the node tag where it makes sense (almost every time)

I have been using this search: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bnode%5D+%22Node.JS%22

There are about 56 that match that search and about 460 total uses of the node tag. I would like to have the node tag to be deleted so it does not get used with node.js and therefore diluted. There is a tag xmlnode for the XML cases.

Could somebody help me with moving off the node tag so I don't have to retag 400 questions?

If you think I am on the wrong track then please let me know.

Comment: It's finally removed. See Jeff's answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104596/please-unsynonym-node-and-node-js

Answer (score 2):

In light of the recent [synonymization](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104596/please-unsynonym-node-and-node-js) of node and node.js, burnination should be operated quickly.

At this time, there are 565 questions tagged with [node](/questions/tagged/node). These breakdown to:

- 
- 
- 
- 
- 
- 
- 
- 
- 
- 

And [others](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/1810/tag-along-tags), but those are the main associations.