# Please unsynonym node and node.js

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

Someone finally went and did it: [node](/questions/tagged/node) and [node.js](/questions/tagged/node.js) are now synonyms. A lot of questions that were about nodes (as part of data structures), are now parading as being about the JavaScript library.

Can we have an undo on this?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85104/moving-off-of-node-tag

Comment: @OAOD yeah, I've tried for the past few weeks to do some cleanup, essentially detagging node when both node and node.js are present.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree that the [node](/questions/tagged/node) tag was quite worthless.

I removed it, and no questions were untagged as a result...

Comment: **"no questions were untagged as a result"** Does that mean the existing questions are still tagged `node`?  Or does it mean that the ones that did still have at least one other tag on them.

Comment: @Jeff You might want to mark this one too as completed: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85104/moving-off-of-node-tag

Comment: @George I think it means that no questions were left with no tags (which tags them with "untagged").

Comment: So what about [tag:nodes]?

Comment: @robert dunno, but unlikely to conflict with [node.js] so probably best brought up as another question

Answer (score 7):

The "node" tag as part of data structures questions is probably **not** a good tag.  That said, this doesn't mean we don't now have some clean-up we need to do that would have been easier *before* the synonym was created.

Comment: Luckily the tags weren't merged, so the cleanup should be minimal.  Only questions created with the `node` tag *after* the synonym was created should be affected.

Comment: Agreed. Cleanup on aisle node!

Comment: It can also be node as in XML node. How useful is it then?

Comment: @MPelletier - Probably still no value there that isn't already communicated via an `xml` tag.

Comment: There's a Drupal node as well. Dammit people, stop calling things 'node'!

Comment: @MPelletier: It is all somehow derived from the graph theoretic nodes, isn't it?

Comment: @Paulo: Not necessarily. Drupal's 'node' refers to a table.

Answer (score 5):

I deleted the synonym.  Luckily the tags weren't merged.

Comment: That doesn't seem to have worked, unless there is some major caching going on. Searching for [node] still takes you to [node.js].  Editing the [node] tag wiki works, but when you save, you wind up at the [node.js] tag wiki page.  WTH?

Comment: @Robert: I think it must be caching.  Searching for [node] is taking me to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/node, with 578 results.